# How to synchronize machines' time

Tags: datetime, batch-file

I am working on 4 machines at a time. It is a real time environment so I have to synchronize the time up to the millisecond, is there anyway to sync the system cliock with millisecond accuracy?

Currently I am syncing the machines with the help of batch script command `NET TIME \\TIMESRV /SET /YES`, but I am not sure that it sync machines time up to millisecond or not. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft does not guarantee such precision:

> We do not guarantee and we do not support the accuracy of the W32Time
>   service between nodes on a network. The W32Time service is not a
>   full-featured NTP solution that meets time-sensitive application
>   needs.
>
> The W32Time service is primarily designed to do the following:
>
> - Make the Kerberos version 5 authentication protocol work.
> - Provide loose sync time for client computers.
>
> The W32Time service cannot reliably maintain sync time to the range of
>   1 to 2 seconds. Such tolerances are outside the design specification
>   of the W32Time service.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322/en-us